# Rewrite SQL query to remove duplicate SELECTs in [WHERE xxx IN] condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to execute following query:

```
DELETE FROM notification 
WHERE account_id IN ( SELECT id FROM missing ) 
   OR receiver_id IN ( SELECT id FROM missing ) 
   OR created_by_id IN ( SELECT id FROM missing ) 
RETURNING id
```

What is bothering me - is that it has to select same values 3 times.
I am sure that there is a better, proper way of doing it.
Could you please suggest how this query might be rewritten?

Comment: It's not selecting the same value 3 times, it's searching for three different values (account_id, receiver_id, created_by_id) in the same table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is going to perform (SELECT id FROM missing) 3 times, right?

Comment: Not because of `SELECT`. You're essentially trying to JOIN three times, on three different columns. If this was a SELECT you could replace the three JOINs with a single one eg `FROM missing on (account_id=missing.id OR ...)`. PostgreSQL doesn't allow JOIN in a DELETE statement but you can do the same with `USING`, eg `USING missing where account_id=missing.id OR ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an EXISTS condition with an IN:

```
delete from notification n
where exists (select *
              from missing m 
              where m.id in (n.account_id, n.receiver_id, n.created_by_id))
returning id;
```

Which is more or less the same as:

```
delete from notification n
using missing m 
where m.id in (n.account_id, n.receiver_id, n.created_by_id)
returning n.id;
```

---

However, the majority of the time will be spent by the actual DELETE part, rather than by finding the rows. So unless `missing` is really huge or a really complicated subquery, I doubt you will see a big performance difference.

---

After a few simple tests (250000 rows in notifications, 10000 rows in missing) it seems that the original version is **way** faster than the EXISTS or USING alternative.

Comment: I suspect that both queries will result in the same execution plan at best *but* the first query is actually simpler and has fewer chances of confusing the query optimizer

Comment: Or `USING missing` to effectively join with `missing`

Comment: The original statement will use 3 Seq Scan on missing, while my statement will only use one. If missing is quite small this will most probably not make a difference, but if it's large the it will

Comment: Duh, when I first read the query I actually saw ... an execution plan graph and thought about JOINs. Took me a while to realize it could also be a single join with 3 conditions

Comment: An alternative with `USING` results in the same execution plan as my query (with a quick test-setup with 1 million rows in `notification`)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried USING but query didn't "compile". Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @walruz: I added the equivalent USING version